# Reference rootURL / any absolute path in hbs

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

The ember-cli-generated index.html file includes this line

```
<script src="{{rootURL}}assets/vendor.js"></script>
```

and `rootURL` is replaced with respective the value from `environment.js` (just `'/'` in develompent).

Now I want to include an icon in a component (in fact, a template used only with `partial`) used in different routes (also at different nesting levels), but

```
<img src="{{rootURL}}assets/img/some_logo.svg">
```

just does not do the trick -- `rootURL` is empty, as is any other string else defined in `environment.js`.

I guess I could create a class file, `import ENV from '../config/environment'` and defined `rootURL: ENV.rootURL`, but surely ember does not expect me to do this whereever I want to include anything from my assets folder, does it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Option 1: `reopen` Controller/Component classes**

The simplest way is to `reopen` to add a property to all Controllers/Components. If you do this, you can use `rootURL` in any template with no other changes required.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ENV from '../config/environment'

Ember.Controller.reopen({
  rootUrl: ENV.rootURL,
});

Ember.Component.reopen({
  rootUrl: ENV.rootURL,
});
```

**Option 2: Controller/Component inheritance**

If you'd like to limit the scope of the change you can you can define a `rootURL` attribute in a base controller/component like application.js:

```
import ENV from '../config/environment'

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  rootURL: ENV.rootURL,
});
```

Then in your other controllers/components, extend that base class and `rootUrl` will work in the corresponding templates:

```
import ApplicationController from 'application';

export default ApplicationController.extend({
  // controller definition
});
```

**Option 3: Controller/Component Mixin**

Instead of using inheritance, you can mixin this functionality to every Controller or Component that you want to have `rootURL`. Start by defining the Mixin:

```
// mixins/with-root.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import ENV from '../config/environment';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  rootURL: ENV.rootURL,
});
```

Use the Mixin in any Component/Controller where you want to use `rootURL` in the template:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import WithRootMixin from '../mixins/with-root';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(WithRootMixin, {
  // controller definition
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know where and when to "reopen" a class in your first solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your `rootURL` is just `/` also in production environment you can modify your image tag as:

```
<img src="/assets/img/some_logo.svg">
```

Otherwise I suppose you should use prepend option for broccoli-asset-rev but I've never tried that:

```
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  // Add options here
  fingerprint: {
    prepend: 'https://cdn.example.com/'
  }
});
```

Official blog post regarding baseURL deprecation: http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/04/28/baseURL.html